# Join a table with a repeated field using UNNEST()

Tags: sql, join, unnest, google-bigquery

I am trying to join two tables, one with a repeated field, using the Standard SQL in BigQuery. Using Legacy SQL I came up with this query

**Legacy SQL**:

```
SELECT
  b.*,
  t.field1,
  t.field2
FROM
  FLATTEN([table1],repeated_field) AS b
LEFT JOIN
  [table2] AS t
ON
  b.Row = t.RowLabel
  b.seat = t.SeatLabel
```

The repeated field is the `seat`. I tried using `unnest()` and looking at the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql), but could not come up with a query myself. Help appreciated thanks.

Comment: How does the data and the response to this query look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT   
  b.*,
  t.field1,
  t.field2
FROM `table1` AS b, UNNEST(Seats) AS Seat
JOIN `table2` AS t
ON b.Row = t.RowLabel
AND Seat = t.SeatLabel
```

You can test it with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table1` AS (
  SELECT '1' AS Row, ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS Seats
),
`table2` AS (
  SELECT '1' AS RowLabel, 'b' AS SeatLabel, 111 AS field1, 222 AS field2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS RowLabel, 'a' AS SeatLabel, 111 AS field1, 222 AS field2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS RowLabel, 'd' AS SeatLabel, 111 AS field1, 222 AS field2
)
SELECT   
  b.*,
  t.field1,
  t.field2
FROM `table1` AS b, UNNEST(Seats) AS Seat
JOIN `table2` AS t
ON b.Row = t.RowLabel
AND Seat = t.SeatLabel
```